# red5 : how can i do Server side live streaming?

Tags: red5

I am using red5 and flex combination for the microphone live streaming.  Scenario is sending web client microphone stream to the server and play the stream on the server side. Similarly, doing the inverse i.e. sending microphone stream from the server to the client and play the stream on the client side.

I have posted the similar query over the stack overflow the link is below:

[red5: how can i send microphone stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602244/red5-how-can-i-send-microphone-stream)

I have got the client side code and I think it is also available on different blogs. But my problem is that how I write the code on red5 server side. I have installed the red5 server on my machine and also read out the red5 API’s. But from there it is not clear how I tackle the live stream on server side.

I have also made a red5 sample code.

**Application.java**

```
public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean appConnect(IConnection arg0, Object[] arg1) {
        out.println("appConnect");
        return super.appConnect(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void appDisconnect(IConnection arg0) {
        out.println("appConnect");
        super.appDisconnect(arg0);
    }

}
```

**StreamManager.java**

```
public class StreamManager {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(StreamManager.class);
    private Application app;

    /**
     * Start recording the publishing stream for the specified IConnection.
     * 
     * @param conn
     */

    private ClientBroadcastStream stream;

    public void recordShow(IConnection conn) {
        try {
            log.debug("Recording show for: " + conn.getScope().getContextPath());
            String streamName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            log.debug("Stream Name : " + streamName);
            // Get a reference to the current broadcast stream.
            stream = (ClientBroadcastStream) app.getBroadcastStream(conn.getScope(), "hostStream");
            // Save the stream to disk.
            stream.saveAs(streamName, false);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public void setApplication(Application app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

}
```

**samplescope-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd"> 
        <bean id="samplescope.context" class="org.red5.server.Context" autowire="byType" />
            <bean id="samplescope.scope" class="org.red5.server.WebScope"
                init-method="register">
                        <property name="server" ref="red5.server" />
                        <property name="parent" ref="global.scope" />
                        <property name="context" ref="samplescope.context" />
                        <property name="handler" ref="samplescope.handler" />
                        <property name="contextPath" value="/samplescope" />
                        <property name="virtualHosts"
                            value="*,localhost, localhost:5080, 127.0.0.1:5080" />                  
            </bean>
    <bean id="samplescope.handler" class="my.first.Application" />
    <bean id="streamManager.service" class="my.first.StreamManager">
        <property name="application" ref="samplescope.handler"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The above code saving the stream in a FLV file on the server side but I want that instead of saving the stream on server I can get raw data stream and so easily encode the stream. Similarly, before sending the stream on server decodes the stream. How can I do it in red5?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the "decoded" media bytes then you have to use something like [Xuggler](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Main_Page) since Red5 does not decode the media. The "codec" classes in Red5 simply store encoded data and send it to wherever it needs to be.